# Parsing XML with xml.etree.ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I'm trying to parse a simple XML block that's passed into the parameter of a function. I then want to return the title within the last `<cd>` element, in this: 'Still got the blues'. For some reason I'm having trouble doing this (first time parsing XML). This is my function right now, which is based on what I've read from the xml.etree.ElementTree documentation:

```
def get_last_title(xmlstr):
  xml = ET.fromstring(xmlstr)
  return xml.findall('cd')[-1:].findall('title').text
```

The XML is here:

```
xml_doc ='''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <artist sex="male">Bob Dylan</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Columbia</company>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1985</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Hide your heart</title>
        <artist sex="female">Bonnie Tyler</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>CBS Records</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1988</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Greatest Hits</title>
        <artist sex="female">Dolly Parton</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>RCA</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1982</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Still got the blues</title>
        <artist sex="male">Gary Moore</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>Virgin records</company>
        <price>10.20</price>
        <year>1990</year>
    </cd>
</catalog>
'''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to slice the list of elements found, instead *get the last element by `-1` index* and then use [`findtext()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.findtext) method to find the inner title:

```
xml.findall('cd')[-1].findtext('title')
```

Demo:

```
>>> import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
>>> 
>>> xml_doc ='''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    Your XML here
... '''
>>> 
>>> xml = ET.fromstring(xml_doc)
>>> print(xml.findall('cd')[-1].findtext('title'))
Still got the blues
```

Comment: Thank you @alecxe!! Worked like a charm. So in this case would element.findall('title').text not work? What about element.find('title').text?

Comment: @Izzy yeah `element.find('title').text` would also work.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how I can search by an attribute such as sex="female"? Apparently it's not element.findall('artist', sex="female").text  :p

Comment: @Izzy sure, there is a limited xpath support but it should be enough: `element.findall('//artist[@sex="female"]'))`

Comment: Thank you! Any idea why I'm getting this error?: SyntaxError: cannot use absolute path on element

Comment: @Izzy ah, sure: `element.findall('.//artist[@sex="female"]'))`